# PCF task scheduling

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cron, jobs, pcfdev

I have a ASP.NET MVC core Web API which is hosted on PCF and I need to create a task scheduler which runs at specified time interval. I am able to do it for a minute but I want to do it for seconds (say 10 seconds).

Currently my CRON job expression for a minute is * * ? * *
What should be my CRON job expression for 10 seconds.

If its not possible in seconds what's the alternative.

I am aware about Hangfire and .NET Quartz but how will I call my controller Get method with dependency injection and also the scheduler should be hosted in PCF?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed DB logic to get more records instead of trying to make PCF scheduling less than a minute.